# Search filter for Year on a date field in template

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, sitecore-query

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA components.
I have checked the SXA out of the box components for search functionality. For date fields, we have date range by which we can filter items in a specific date range value. 
There is a filter dropdown also, which works only n integer facets.

**Can we have a date field in a template and then filter the items by year?**

Example, we have below date fields in item values:

- 12th January 2016
- 18th May 2015
- 31st March 2015

In search field dropdown, we will have 2 options as 2016 and 2015.
On select of 2015, it will display the 2nd and 3rd item.

I am pretty new to Sitecore and SXA, any links or references will be much helpful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is already similar question here -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/5791/2056 .Difference is that they are sorting and you need to filter. I believe that you need to do one or two more steps and you are there..

Comment: @PeterProchazka : Thanks for the quick response, but they are just sorting using date, I want to filter using year of the date, not the full date part, I kind of want to group results by year !!