# Sort SXA search results by date without SXA sorting rendering

Tags: sxa, content-search

I have a list of blogs, and I'm using the Search Results component to render them. I need to order them by date: specifically, to show the most recent ones first, so they'd be ordered newest date first.

Is there a way to do this without using the "sorting" SXA component? Maybe using something specific in the Scope query?

I've already checked this answer [Sitecore SXA Search Result Sorting by date](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/sitecore-sxa-search-result-sorting-by-date) where they use the SXA sorting rendering to accomplish this,but it's not what i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Search Results rendering has `Default sort order` setting in the Control Properties:

[image]

Those configurations as you probably already know are stored under this item `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Data/Search/Sort Results`. Take a look:

[image]

Comment: I'd created a "Date Facet" and a "Date Desc sorting" connected to it, but i hadn't noticed I can choose it from the settings of the "Search Results rendering" itself, rather than only in the "SXA sorting rendering", thank you!